# SQL Query - One to Many relationship where all "Many" have a specific attribute

Tags: sql

I am a bit rusty in Queries and I can't seem to find the solution for a problem that I have.

I'll make an analogy with sports.

Let's say we have a One to Many relationship between Teams (1-*) Games so each team has multiple games.

The Table Games has an attribute called Result which is an Enum and can have Victory or Loss.

I want to list all the teams where all Results are Victories.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't think it matters for this question. The answer is so simple, it can be used in almost any environment :)

Comment: Use NOT EXISTS, pseudocode: `select * from Teams t where not exists( select 1 from Games g where g is_related_to t  and g.Result = Loss) `

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do the job :)

```
select t.name

from teams t

where
(select COUNT(*) from games g where g.teamid = t.teamid and g.result = 1 --victory) > 0

AND (select COUNT(*) from games g where g.teamid = t.teamid and g.result = 0 --Loss) = 0
```

Comment: This will return teams which have at least 1 Victory and probably have a number of Losses as well, contrary to OP's request.

Comment: If you're thinking in sets, usually you'd want an empty set to be considered a match for an `ALL` predicate (referred to as "vacuously true"). I.e. for a team who have *no* results, it's vacuously true that all of their results are victories. Also, it's generally poor form to *count* when all you care about are *existence* or non-existence.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ... No. If someone wants teams where all results are victories, they would not expect to see teams with no games in that list.